# How to change a pointer value in a function without pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm trying to brush on my skills in C and am working on linked lists. I was also trying to not have the head be a global variable (allows the function to be more generic). The issue I have is how to change where the head points to without using a pointer to a pointer.

Here is the code I tried but didn't work; head was not being changed to point to the second node. (I think this is the original code, or at least close to it. I have fixed it to use double pointers so...)

```
int nodeRemove(Node*top, int data)
{
    if(top == NULL)
        return -1;

    Node *current = top;
    Node *previous = top;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->data == data)
        {
            if(current == top)
            {
                top = current->next;
            }
            else
            {
                previous->next = current->next;
                free(current);
            }
            return 1;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

I finally changed the code to be as such...

```
int nodeRemove(Node **top, int data)
{
    if(top == NULL)
        return -1;

    Node *current = *top;
    Node *previous = *top;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if(current->data == data)
        {
            if(current == *top)
            {
                *top = current->next;
                free(current);
            }
            else
            {
                previous->next = current->next;
                free(current);
            }
            return 1;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

But I was wondering two things

1. Why can't I change head to point to the second node like I can have the second node point to the fourth thus removing node 3 from the list?
2. Is there a way to do this without using a double pointer. If so, how and why does that work while my original method does not?

Comment: If a function needs to be able to change a variable in the caller, there are two things you can do:  (1) Pass a pointer to it (as you've done), or (2) Have the function return the new value, and have the caller assign that return value to its variable.  Those are by far the two most common ways to handle this.  Pick one.

Comment: To avoid confusion in "pointer-to-pointer" cases, you can use either "pointer to typedef (which is a pointer)" or "pointer to struct containing pointer".

Comment: You can also store the pointer in a struct.

Comment: The question is, are you building the LL with a function like `addNode( ... ) {` How does that function update the `head` pointer in the caller??

Comment: @Kasriel Lewis, "how to change where the head points to without using a pointer to a pointer." --> Have the _head_ be something other than a pointer  (e.g. a `struct`), then pass the address of the `struct`.  Of course now you have a pointer to a `struct`.  Not quite the same as a pointer to pointer, yet maybe too much alike for your goals.

Comment: @Kasriel Lewis,  Yet to get to the root of the issue: **why** do you not want to "... without using a pointer to a pointer."?  What issue is really of concern?

Comment: Both your `nodeRemove` functions are missing a `return` statement (with a value) at the end.

Comment: Pointer to pointer (`Node **top` local parameter or variable) also allows you to do this: `while ((current = *top) != NULL)` `{` `if ((current->data == data)` `{` `*top = current->next;` `free(current);` `return 1;` `}` `top = &current->next;` `}` `return NOTFOUND;`.

Comment: You have changed the semantics, you have changed all expressions of `top` into `*top`, except for the first in the starting `if`.  This will make your function to fail only in case you pass a NULL pointer reference (but not a reference whose data points to `NULL`, as it was in the first version)  If the intention was to pass the pointer by reference, you should change also that first if (and add an `assert(top != NULL);` on top, to disallow null references to pointers)

Answer (score 3):

In C arguments are passed by value (copy).  The general rule is that if you want to change an argument in a function (aka an out param) then you need to pass in it's address.  In this case you want to change a pointer then you need to know the address of the pointer hence the double indirection (`Node **top`). This is the standard way of doing things.

Here are some other options:

You can store the pointer in struct:

```
struct LinkedList {
    struct Node *head;
} LinkedList;
```

Which you would use like this:

```
LinkedList ll;
// ...
nodeRemove(&ll, 42);
```

This makes more sense if you want to store other attributes of the linked list, like a pointer to the tail, or number of elements in the list etc.

Function can return the new value and caller is responsible for updating it's pointer value:

```
Node *root;
// ...
root = nodeRemove(root, 42);
```

Technically, you could keep the root as is, but copy the data from the 2nd node, and free that 2nd node instead.  You need to think about what should happen if you need to remove the last element:

```
int nodeRemove(Node *top, int data)
{
   if(top->data == data) {
      struct Node *tmp = top->next;
      if(!tmp) {
          top->data = tmp->data;
          top->next = tmp->next->next;
          free(tmp);
          return 1;
      }  else {
         // TBD
      }
   }
   // ...
}
```

Usually, remove implies a free, but you could also maintain a free list.  `root` could remain as is, but you need to look at the free list to see if a given node is still valid.  This design, alone, will not work if need to change the order of nodes, say, sorting it, or inserting a new node as root.

Comment: If that answered your question please accept it by clicking the check mark next to it. That way we know you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(top == NULL)
        return -1;
```

should have become

```
    assert(top != NULL); /* this will never be allowed, as a program error */
    if (*top == NULL)
        return -1;
```

if you don't, then you'll change the semantics with the refactoring you have done.

The approach of converting a pointer to a root node pointer to pass it by reference (that allows you to modify the original pointer in case it is the one to be deleted) requires you first disallow to ever pass it a null pointer (which is what the assertion does) then you have to dereference it, to detect for passing it a pointer that stores a `NULL` value (which is still allowed)

Now, `top` is a reference to a pointer, to move it through the list, you need to make it  point to the `next` pointer in the node referenced by `*top`, this is:

```
    top = &(*top)->next;
```

this is, `top` will point to the `next` address field of the node referenced by `*top`.

Unlinking the node in the chain is simple  (and using the reference you don't need to check if you are unlinking the last node in the list, as it has a `next` field pointing to `NULL`), but you need to save the referenced node first, as you lose it in the unlink process, to be able to `free()` it:

```
    Node* const saved = *top;
    top = &saved->next;  /* make point to point to the next field reference */
    free(saved);
```

(I've used `&saved->next`, instead of the more embarrasing `&(*top)->next` expression above, taking advantage of the already dereferenced pointer used in `saved`)